# Flutter create instant-enabled Android App Bundle

Tags: android, deployment, flutter, release

How can I create an instant-enabled app bundle Flutter?

A [post on medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/making-the-amp-sample-an-instant-app-30c3f0a050af) lead me to add the following to the android manifest:

> ```
> <application...>
>     <!-- Enable instant app support -->
>     <dist:module dist:instant="true" />
> ```

The bundle successfully builds, however it is not instant enabled, or at least it so it says the play store.

Comment: In case you are trying test your app on google play console, I found another way around. On the google play console menu , click on "Development tools" instead of "Release magement" and there you will and "Internal app sharing" option where you can upload any bundle and share the app to anyone with a link.

Answer (score 0):

Aggreed with Ignacio Catalan. I dont have the points to confirm his comments.

I did not need to change anything to the appbundle build other than find a different location to upload directly to the app sharing locaiton.

```
https://play.google.com/apps/publish/internalappsharing/
```

You can use the above link or follow his steps

As he mentioned you can find if you clicked on the "Learn More" link of instant apps under "Development Tools". Or just use the above link.